# MUP auto extend let's encrypt

Tags: meteor, lets-encrypt, meteor-up

I need to auto extend my certificates but without manually configuring certbot or any action that would require me to SSH into the server. How is or possible to do it only using the mup config file and maybe hooks + js files?

Comment: mup does that automatically by default, no? At least it does for me.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor-up (mup) does so automatically. A configuration like this works for me in `mup.js`:

```
  proxy: {
    domains: 'example.com,www.example.com,example.org',
    ssl: {
      letsEncryptEmail: 'your-email-for-letsencrypt@somewhere.com'
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have exactly this configuration but I still get after 60 days expiration emails and that I have to manually renew the certificat

Comment: The docs say it's supposed to renew automatically 30 days before expiry.  https://meteor-up.com/docs#ssl
I ended up on this page because I had changed the domain name of the site without updating mup.js, so the cert didn't renew automatically.  I needed to set `servers: one: host: "my.domain.blah"` and `proxy: domains: "my.domain.blah"`.
After mup.js is correct, rerunning `mup setup` and `mup reconfig` should create the new cert.  Hopefully it will renew automatically in a few months.